# Callback function does not see correct values in instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, callback, zeromq

I'm having a strange phenomena in Python with callback functions and handlers. 
I use ZMQ to handle my communication and use a stream for the socket. I have the base class:

```
import multiprocessing    
import zmq
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop, zmqstream
from zmq.utils import jsonapi as json

# Types of messages
TYPE_A = 'type_a'
TYPE_B = 'type_b'


class ZmqProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ZmqProcess, self).__init__()
        self.context = None
        self.loop = None
        self.handle_stream = None

    def setup(self):
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.loop = ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

    def send(self, msg_type, msg, host, port):
        sock = zmq.Context().socket(zmq.PAIR)
        sock.connect('tcp://%s:%s' % (host, port))
        sock.send_json([msg_type, msg])

    def stream(self, sock_type, addr):
        sock = self.context.socket(sock_type)
            if isinstance(addr, str):
            addr = addr.split(':')
        host, port = addr if len(addr) == 2 else (addr[0], None)
            if port:
            sock.bind('tcp://%s:%s' % (host, port))
        else:
            port = sock.bind_to_random_port('tcp://%s' % host)
        stream = zmqstream.ZMQStream(sock, self.loop)    
        return stream, int(port)

class MessageHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, json_load=-1):
        self._json_load = json_load
        self.pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)

    def __call__(self, msg):
        i = self._json_load
        msg_type, data = json.loads(msg[i])
        msg[i] = data
        if msg_type.startswith('_'):
            raise AttributeError('%s starts with an "_"' % msg_type)
        getattr(self, msg_type)(*msg)
```

And I have a class that inherits from it:

```
import zmq    
import zmq_base    

class ZmqServerMeta(zmq_base.ZmqProcess):
    def __init__(self, bind_addr, handlers):
        super(ZmqServerMeta, self).__init__()
        self.bind_addr = bind_addr
        self.handlers = handlers

    def setup(self):
        super(ZmqServerMeta, self).setup()
        self.handle_stream, _ = self.stream(zmq.PAIR, self.bind_addr)
        self.handle_stream.on_recv(StreamHandler(self.handle_stream, self.stop,
                                                 self.handlers))

    def run(self):
        self.setup()
        self.loop.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.loop.stop()

class StreamHandler(zmq_base.MessageHandler):
    def __init__(self, handle_stream, stop, handlers):
        super(StreamHandler, self).__init__()
        self._handle_stream = handle_stream
        self._stop = stop
        self._handlers = handlers

    def type_a(self, data):
        if zmq_base.TYPE_A in self._handlers:
            if self._handlers[zmq_base.TYPE_A]:
                for handle in self._handlers[zmq_base.TYPE_A]:
                    self.pool.submit(handle, data)
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass

    def type_b(self, data):
        if zmq_base.TYPE_B in self._handlers:
            if self._handlers[zmq_base.TYPE_B]:
                for handle in self._handlers[zmq_base.TYPE_B]:
                    self.pool.submit(handle, data)
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass

    def endit(self):
        self._stop()
```

Additionally, I have a class that I want to use as storage. And here is where the trouble starts:

```
import threading
import zmq_server_meta as server
import zmq_base as base


class Storage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

        self.list_lock = threading.RLock()

        self.zmq_server = None
        self.host = '127.0.0.1'
        self.port = 5432
        self.bind_addr = (self.host, self.port)

    def setup(self):
        handlers = {base.TYPE_A: [self. remove]}
        self.zmq_server = server.ZmqServerMeta(handlers=handlers, bind_addr=self.bind_addr)
        self.zmq_server.start()

    def add(self, data):
        with self.list_lock:
            try:
                self.list.append(data)
            except:
                print "Didn't work"

    def remove(self, msg):
        with self.list_lock:
            try:
                self.list.remove(msg)
            except:
                print "Didn't work"
```

The idea is that that class stores some global information that it receives. 
It is all started in a file to test:

```
import sys
import time
import storage
import zmq_base as base
import zmq_server_meta as server



def printMsg(msg):
    print msg

store = storage.Storage()

store.setup()
handlers = {base.TYPE_B: [printMsg]}
client = server.ZmqServerMeta(handlers=handlers, bind_addr=('127.0.0.1', 5431))
client.start()

message = "Test"

store.add(message)
client.send(base.TYPE_A, message, '127.0.0.1', 5432)
```

I simplified it to reduce clutter. Instead of just adding it, it is usually send and then a response comes back. The response, the client sending, should be processed by the correct callback, remove(), and it should remove something out of the list. The problem that occurs is, that the remove() function sees an empty list, although there should be an element in the list. If I check from the testing file, I can see the element after it was added, and if I call remove() from there, I see a non-empty list and can remove it. My question is, why does the callback sees an empty list and how can I make sure it does see the correct elements in the list?

Kind regards
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem lays in the fact that the ZmqProcess class inherits from multiprocessing.Process. Multiprocessing does not allow to share objects among different processes, except by using a shared memory map using Value or Array ( as can be seen in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes )

If you want to use your custom object, you can use a Server process / proxy object, which can be found in on the same page of the documentation.

So you can, for instance, define a manager in the init function of the Storage class like:  `self.manager = Manager()` Afterwards you put `self.list = self.manager.list()`. This should do the trick.